# Using 2 batteries with a thinkpad t480

Tags: gnome, 18.04, battery, thinkpad

How does Ubuntu decide which battery to use? The laptop is designed so that you can swap out the extra battery (If extra means 'removable' in Gnome), so it would make sense to default to drawing power form the removable battery always, and only use the built in one if it needs to. This would maintain the health of the battery I cannot replace as well.

Is there a way to get it to default to drawing from the removable battery?

Comment: Ubuntu or any other OS typically do not control such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Ubuntu doesn't decide which battery to use.

Long answer: your ThinkPad's embedded controller (EC) firmware decides when to use (and charge) which battery. The firmware policy is fixed and the operating system or apps are not allowed to change it.

Comment: Hm..do you what happens if it's using the removable battery and that one runs out? Or if I can remove it when it's nearly used up and put in another battery?

Comment: It switches to the internal battery. External battery is hot swappable. See http://blog.lenovo.com/en/blog/all-about-power-bridge-technology